# Proof Using Multinomial Coefficients Verification

Tags: proof-verification, multinomial-coefficients

> Use multinomial coefficients to prove that, for all positive integers
>   n,
>
> $6^n=\binom{n}{0}5^n+\binom{n}{1}5^{n-1}+\binom{n}{2}5^{n-2}+\cdots
>  +\binom{n}{n}5^0$
>
> Provide a clear proof and all working, justifying and explaining all
>   steps taken.

I have posted this question before, but I had included a different proof to the one I'm including now. Hopefully, this will be a little easier to interpret.

The proof I've come up with is below:
[image]

Is this proof okay? I'm open to any suggestions! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a concise way to write it.
By the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem),
$$
\left(1+x\right)^{n}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}1^{k}x^{n-k}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}.
$$
Taking $x=5$ gives you the special case you mention.

Comment: I agree that the way you mentioned is the best way to prove it, but the question specifically requires one to use multinomial coefficients. Thus, I wanted to verify that my proof was correct as I'm not too confident proving the case with what is required by the question.

Comment: Binomial coefficients *are* a special subset of the multinomial coefficients. You can see them appearing in the proof I give. Also, I don't see any non-binomial multinomial coefficients in your proof.

Comment: True, I guess you're right. Thank you!